# Resampling Dataframe from Monthly to Daily

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

Here is my problem:

This is a sample of my DataFrame (it actually goes from 2002 to 2012)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date':["2002-07-31","2002-07-31","2002-07-31","2002-07-31","2002-07-31","2002-08-31","2002-08-31","2002-08-31","2002-08-31","2002-08-31",'2002-09-30','2002-09-30','2002-09-30','2002-09-30','2002-09-30'],
     'Name': ["Paul", "John", "Silvia", "Mike", "Cindy","Paul", "David", "Harry", "Mike", "Britney","Francis", "Michael", "Charlie", "Joe", "Hilary"]})
```

Which gives this

```
       Date     Name
0   2002-07-31  Paul
1   2002-07-31  John
2   2002-07-31  Silvia
3   2002-07-31  Mike
4   2002-07-31  Cindy
5   2002-08-31  Paul
6   2002-08-31  David
7   2002-08-31  Harry
8   2002-08-31  Mike
9   2002-08-31  Britney
10  2002-09-30  Francis
11  2002-09-30  Michael
12  2002-09-30  Charlie
13  2002-09-30  Joe
14  2002-09-30  Hilary
```

and I would like to resample the serie from Monthly to Daily DataFrame by keeping all the names fix from 2002-07-31 to 2002-08-30 and from 2002-08-31 to 2002-09-30 (the change only occurs at the end of each month so it looks like resampling with the ffill() method).

The result I am looking for is something like that :

```
   Date     Name
2002-07-31  Paul
2002-07-31  John
2002-07-31  Silvia
2002-07-31  Mike
2002-07-31  Cindy
2002-08-01  Paul
2002-08-01  John
2002-08-01  Silvia
2002-08-01  Mike
2002-08-01  Cindy
2002-08-02  Paul
2002-08-02  John
2002-08-02  Silvia
2002-08-02  Mike
2002-08-02  Cindy
2002-08-03  Paul
2002-08-03  John
2002-08-03  Silvia
2002-08-03  Mike
2002-08-03  Cindy
.....

2002-08-31  Paul
2002-08-31  David
2002-08-31  Harry
2002-08-31  Mike
2002-08-31  Britney
2002-09-01  Paul
2002-09-01  David
2002-09-01  Harry
2002-09-01  Mike
2002-09-01  Britney
....

2002-09-30  Francis
2002-09-30  Michael
2002-09-30  Charlie
2002-09-30  Joe
2002-09-30  Hilary
```

As you can see, the names only change at the end of each month. 
The most difficult step for me is that I have a selection of 5 names, and I don't really know how to resample to a daily Dataframe and still having 5 names for each day.

I already looked at this link

[Resampling Error : cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792933/resampling-error-cannot-reindex-a-non-unique-index-with-a-method-or-limit)

But It is not really the same issue and I still don't find any solution to manage mine. 
If you have any ideas, you are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ensure your `Date` column is a `datetime` object:

```
df['Date'] = df.Date.astype('datetime64')
```

Then, group by the `Date` column, aggregate the names to `list`, `resample` by day and fill, finally perform an `explode` to expand the `list`s of names:

```
df.groupby('Date').agg(list).resample('D').ffill().explode('Name').reset_index()

# Result:
          Date     Name
0   2002-07-31     Paul
1   2002-07-31     John
2   2002-07-31   Silvia
3   2002-07-31     Mike
4   2002-07-31    Cindy
..         ...      ...
305 2002-09-30  Francis
306 2002-09-30  Michael
307 2002-09-30  Charlie
308 2002-09-30      Joe
309 2002-09-30   Hilary

[310 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would pivot the data and use `asfreq` to sample the data, then stack:

```
(df.assign(group=df.groupby('Date').cumcount())
  .set_index(['Date','group'])['Name']
  .unstack()
  .asfreq('D').ffill()
  .unstack()
  .reset_index('group',drop=True)
  .reset_index(name='Name')
)
```

Output:

```
          Date     Name
0   2002-07-31     Paul
1   2002-07-31     John
2   2002-07-31   Silvia
3   2002-07-31     Mike
4   2002-07-31    Cindy
..         ...      ...
305 2002-09-30  Francis
306 2002-09-30  Michael
307 2002-09-30  Charlie
308 2002-09-30      Joe
309 2002-09-30   Hilary

[310 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!